# Context3D not available! Possible reasons: wrong wmode or missing device support

Tags: 16.04, firefox, games, webapps

I'm trying to play a game on [360Game](https://360game.vn/) but I am getting the following error:

> Context3D not available! Possible reasons: wrong wmode or missing device support.

[image]

What could be the issue? How can I fix it? 
I am using Firefox 68.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.6

Comment: Can we use wine?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? Which version of Firefox is it? Have you tried on other browsers like Chrome?

Comment: sorry i don't know anything about ubuntu, i have flash download but don't know how to activate it

Comment: Click on the Ubuntu logo on top-left side and search for terminal. Click on that and type `lsb_release -a; firefox -v` and hit enter. You might get some output. Copy the text and paste in question body using [edit].

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
Mozilla Firefox 68.0

Comment: This is a 2 year old thread. See if it helps: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1156131

Comment: Can you guide me to see if I am using ubuntu 32bit or 64bit ? tks 4 everything

Comment: Please open a terminal and do `uname -m`. If the answer is x86_64, you have 64-bit; otherwise, it's 32-bit.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your patience

Answer (score 1):

That's more of a browser question than an Ubuntu question.

I would suggest trying some other browsers first, such as [Brave](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/12/how-to-install-brave-web-browser-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/) being my favorite, Chromium, etc...  See if that makes a difference.

The game may need the [Flash plugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html.en), which is deprecated and the world is moving away from it, but it can still be done if absolutely needed.

The game may be a Microsoft Active-X game - which based on the error may be likely - in which case [there may not be a reasonable fix](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3730e5b-c36a-4dac-917e-76661d8c06cf/activex-on-linux?forum=Offtopic).

The game may be a Java game, try making sure you have the [Java plugin](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser_ubuntu.xml) installed.

Comment: This is the best way to use ubuntu and i'm not really good at english. I downloaded a lot of files but could not start them. I don't know how to get started in common. I hope everyone can show you some things about ubuntu

Comment: http://gamek.vn/hien-tai-game-thu-dung-linux-da-co-the-choi-game-thoai-mai-20180721153556741.chn

Answer (score 0):

Research shows (thank you, Kulfy!) this is a Flash based issue, and the website developer uses tools which don't work well with 64-bit Firefox. However, since Firefox is Open Source, other developers have a spin-off Firefox based browser which is 32-bit, for Ubuntu 16.04.

It's called [Pale Moon](https://linux.palemoon.org/) and you can [download the installation files](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/stevenpusser/xUbuntu_16.04/i386/palemoon_28.6.0.1+repack-1_i386.deb). Once downloaded, do `sudo dpkg -i palemoon_28.6.0.1+repack-1_i386.deb` to install Pale Moon.  Once you start Pale Moon, you will see it's Firefox with some different colors, and will take nearly all the Firefox plugins and extensions (excepting, of course, 64-bit add-ons).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the `wmode` requests a specific parameter from the browser.
The solution's download Opera browser - full support for legacy now, flash player games.

[https://www.opera.com](https://www.opera.com/pl)